# Convert as image and download a div element that contains html, images and svg:JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to convert div to image and download. I have a script to convert div to image and convert svg to image independently.

If I convert the parent div to image, it's not converting child svg as well.

But, I have div that contains images, html contents and svg, I want to convert all together as image as I see the div on screen using javascript.

**Chart appears in browser is:**
[chart as it is in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLVYu.png)

**Exported image looks:**
[exported image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov4BG.png)

In this exported image svg shape is not showing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**My sample code:**

```js
window.exportAsImage = function() {
  var target = document.getElementById("chart-container-plan_vs_achieved");
     html2canvas(target, {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
   var imgageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
   var link = document.createElement("a");
   link.style.display = "none";
   link.setAttribute("download", "myImage.png");
   link.setAttribute("href", newData);
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
   link.remove();
  }
     });
 }
```

```css
.target{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:#DDCCAA;
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container-plan_vs_achieved" class=" x-component" style="width: 382px; height: 208px;"><div style="width: 382px; height: 166.4px; float: left; text-align: center;" widthpercent="100.0" heightpercent="80" id="chart-holder-plan_vs_achieved-0"><span id="chartobject-19" style="position: relative; text-align: left; line-height: normal; display: inline-block; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: medium none; direction: ltr; width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="fusioncharts-container"><svg height="166" version="1.1" width="382" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" id="raphael-paper-755"><desc>Column Chart</desc><defs><clipPath id="9B15D3FA-95F4-4822-856F-0481ACEE3FA1"><rect x="34" y="17" width="331" height="118" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"/></clipPath></defs><g class="raphael-group-756-background"><rect style="stroke: none; fill-opacity: 0.5; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" x="0" y="0" width="382" height="166" stroke="none" fill-opacity="0.5" fill="#ffffff" rx="0" ry="0"/><rect style="stroke: rgb(118, 117, 117); stroke-opacity: 0.5; fill: none;" x="0" y="0" width="382" height="166" stroke="#767575" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="none" fill="none" rx="0" ry="0"/></g><g class="raphael-group-763-canvas"><rect style="stroke: rgb(84, 84, 84); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linejoin: miter; fill: none;" x="33" y="16" width="333" height="120" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="#545454" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linejoin="miter" fill="none"/><rect style="stroke: none; fill-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);" x="34" y="17" width="331" height="118" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" fill-opacity="1" fill="#ffffff"/></g><g class="raphael-group-766-axisbottom"><g class="raphael-group-769-x-axis-bands"/><g class="raphael-group-775-y-axis-bands"><rect style="fill-opacity: 0.5; fill: rgb(238, 238, 238); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" x="34" y="87.80000000000001" width="331" height="23.599999999999994" fill-opacity="0.5" fill="#eeeeee" stroke-width="0" rx="0" ry="0" stroke="#000000"/><rect style="fill-opacity: 0.5; fill: rgb(238, 238, 238); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" x="34" y="40.60000000000001" width="331" height="23.599999999999994" fill-opacity="0.5" fill="#eeeeee" stroke-width="0" rx="0" ry="0" stroke="#000000"/></g><g class="raphael-group-781-y-axis-bands"/><g class="raphael-group-771-x-axis-lines"/><g class="raphael-group-777-y-axis-lines"><path style="stroke: rgb(113, 113, 112); stroke-opacity: 0.4; fill: none; shape-rendering: crispedges;" d="M34,111.5L365,111.5" stroke="#717170" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="none" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/><path style="stroke: rgb(113, 113, 112); stroke-opacity: 0.4; fill: none; shape-rendering: crispedges;" d="M34,88.5L365,88.5" stroke="#717170" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="none" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/><path style="stroke: rgb(113, 113, 112); stroke-opacity: 0.4; fill: none; shape-rendering: crispedges;" d="M34,64.5L365,64.5" stroke="#717170" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="none" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/><path style="stroke: rgb(113, 113, 112); stroke-opacity: 0.4; fill: none; shape-rendering: crispedges;" d="M34,41.5L365,41.5" stroke="#717170" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="none" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/></g><g class="raphael-group-783-y-axis-lines"/><g class="fusioncharts-xaxis-0-gridlabels" style=""><text style="fill-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: middle; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill-opacity="1" fill="#555555" x="116.75" y="151" text-anchor="middle" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal"><tspan dy="-2.5" x="116.75">Planned</tspan></text><text style="fill-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: middle; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill-opacity="1" fill="#555555" x="282.25" y="151" text-anchor="middle" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal"><tspan dy="-2.5" x="282.25">Achived</tspan></text></g><g class="fusioncharts-yaxis-0-gridlabels" style=""><text style="fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: end; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill="#555555" x="28" y="135" text-anchor="end" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="undefined" font-style="undefined"><tspan dy="3.5" x="28">0</tspan></text><text style="fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: end; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill="#555555" x="28" y="111.4" text-anchor="end" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="undefined" font-style="undefined"><tspan dy="3.4999984741210994" x="28">1K</tspan></text><text style="fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: end; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill="#555555" x="28" y="87.80000000000001" text-anchor="end" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="undefined" font-style="undefined"><tspan dy="3.499996948242199" x="28">2K</tspan></text><text style="fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: end; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill="#555555" x="28" y="64.2" text-anchor="end" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="undefined" font-style="undefined"><tspan dy="3.5000030517578153" x="28">3K</tspan></text><text style="fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: end; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill="#555555" x="28" y="40.60000000000001" text-anchor="end" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="undefined" font-style="undefined"><tspan dy="3.5000015258789148" x="28">4K</tspan></text><text style="fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); text-anchor: end; stroke: none; font-family: Verdana,sans; font-size: 10px;" class="fusioncharts-label" fill="#555555" x="28" y="17" text-anchor="end" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" stroke="none" font-family="Verdana,sans" font-size="10px" font-weight="undefined" font-style="undefined"><tspan dy="3.5" x="28">5K</tspan></text></g><g class="fusioncharts-yaxis-1-gridlabels" style=""/><g class="raphael-group-786-axis-name"/></g><g class="raphael-group-757-dataset"><g class="raphael-group-801-columns" style="" clip-path="url('#9B15D3FA-95F4-4822-856F-0481ACEE3FA1')"><rect style="fill-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(0, 117, 194); stroke: rgb(51, 51, 51); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linejoin: miter;" x="91.5" y="34.5" width="50" height="101" rx="0" ry="0" fill-opacity="1" fill="#0075c2" stroke="#333333" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-linejoin="miter"/><rect style="fill-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(26, 175, 93); stroke: rgb(51, 51, 51); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linejoin: miter;" x="257.5" y="104.5" width="50" height="31" rx="0" ry="0" fill-opacity="1" fill="#1aaf5d" stroke="#333333" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-linejoin="miter"/></g></g><g class="raphael-group-767-axistop"><g class="raphael-group-768-x-axis-bands"/><g class="raphael-group-774-y-axis-bands"/><g class="raphael-group-780-y-axis-bands"/><g class="raphael-group-770-x-axis-lines"/><g class="raphael-group-776-y-axis-lines"/><g class="raphael-group-782-y-axis-lines"/><g class="fusioncharts-xaxis-0-gridlabels" style=""/><g class="fusioncharts-yaxis-0-gridlabels" style=""/><g class="fusioncharts-yaxis-1-gridlabels" style=""/></g><g class="fusioncharts-datalabels" style="" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><text style="fill-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-size: 10px; stroke: none; text-anchor: middle;" class="fusioncharts-label" x="116.5" y="22.5" fill-opacity="1" fill="#555555" font-size="10px" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle"><tspan dy="3.5" x="116.5">4.2K</tspan></text><text style="fill-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-size: 10px; stroke: none; text-anchor: middle;" class="fusioncharts-label" x="282.5" y="92.5" fill-opacity="1" fill="#555555" font-size="10px" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle"><tspan dy="3.5" x="282.5">1.3K</tspan></text></g><g class="raphael-group-758-hot"/><g class="raphael-group-761-buttons"/></svg></span></div><div style="width: 382px; height: 41px; float: left; text-align: center;" widthpercent="100.0" heightpercent="20.0" id="chart-attachment-holder-plan_vs_achieved"><div style="display:table;text-align:center;width:100%;height:100%;"><div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle; color:#F2C500; font-size:24px;">30.4%</div></div></div></div>

<input type="button" value="export" name = "export" onclick="exportAsImage()"/>
```

Comment: First, use the latest version of html2canvas, then, if you already have a script to convert your svg to bitmap, use it first and replace your svg node with the bitmap result. (Note that if you need to support IE browsers, only parsing the svg and using the canvas'API drawing methods to reproduce it will make an exportable version of your svgs. So check that your library indeed does this (by default, I think html2canvas uses `drawImage` which will taint the canvas in these browsers...

Comment: I think if you have correct base64 ecncoded data then an anchor with download attribute can do the job [Download Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: Try [this one](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) on your svg before processing html2canvas

Comment: Please somebody help me about this.. i tired all you guys said. could not achieve my expectation ...